# C++ map isn't finding key even though it exists

Tags: c++, unreal

I am in the process of learning C++ for the Unreal engine.
I am trying to figure out why when I use the [] operator on a map<Vector2, ControlNode> with a value that *I know* is in the map, it returns nullptr.

Here are the relevant pieces of code:

**Vector2**

```
**Vector2.h**
class MAGICGAME2D_API Vector2
{
public:
    Vector2(float x, float z);
    Vector2();
    float X;
    float Z;

public:
    friend bool operator< (const Vector2& c1, const Vector2& c2);

};

**Vector.cpp**
bool operator< (const Vector2& c1, const Vector2& c2)
{
    return (c1.X < c2.X ||
        c1.Z < c2.Z);
}
```

Creating the map:

```
for(auto values : *data->getAutomata()) {
    auto pos = values.first;
    shared_ptr<ControlNode> node = make_shared<ControlNode>(pos,values.second);
    controlNodes.emplace(pos,node);
}
```

And this is the place I make the call to check if the value is in the map:

```
shared_ptr<ControlNode> node = (*(*data).getControlNodes())[pos];
```

The data variable is a pointer, that points to an object that holds a shared_ptrstd::map<Vector2,shared_ptr<ControlNode>>. So that is why I am double dereferencing that part of the code.

This call to retrieve from the map acts a bit odd. Sometimes it will work. For example, where `pos = Vector2(0,0)`. But then it will fail where `pos = Vector2(0,25)`, and it will return a nullptr. The weird thing is that I have confirmed that `pos = Vector2(0,25)` is already in the map.

Is there something I am doing wrong with the call to retrieve the `shared_ptr<ControlNode>`?

Comment: The way you've defined operator < does not produce a consistent total order over the set of possible vectors. (0, 25) < (25, 0) evaluates to true, but so does (25, 0) < (0, 25). Think of how that influences where (0, 25) might get inserted in your map based on what was there previously, and whether you can reliably find your way there later no matter what was inserted in between.

Comment: Welcome to [gamedev.se]! Although you're working in the context of writing a game, this is considered a general programming issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As noted in the comments](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/185874/c-map-isnt-finding-key-even-though-it-exists#comment334949_185874), your `operator<` is wrong.

For `std::map` to function properly, the `operator<` must follow the so-called [*strict weak order*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LessThanComparable). It may sound complicated, but it just means that `operator<` must produce sensible results.

With your implementation, given for example `a = Vector2(1,0);` `b = Vector2(0,1);`, both `a < b` and `b < a` return true at the same time, which doesn't qualify as "sensible results".

A proper implementation of `operator<` could look like this:

```cpp
if (c1.X != c2.X) return c1.X < c2.X;
if (c1.Z != c2.Z) return c1.Z < c2.Z;
return false.
```

Or, the same thing but shorter:

```
return std::tie(c1.X, c1.Z) < std::tie(c2.X, c2.Z);
```